# Linking error in C and Mysql

Tags: mysql, c, makefile, cgi

Hi I'm developing CGI which is written in C and trying to use Mysql.
When I try to use it, I got those undefined reference errors for symbols that start with mysql_, such as those shown here:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `password' changed from 2 to 1 in ../../lib    /libcgi_module.a(users.o)
../../lib/libcgi_module.a(users.o): In function `save':
/home/jitcomm/intern_GUI/jit24_test_v2/cgi_src/cgi_module/users.c:18: multiple definition of `save'
../../lib/libcgi_module.a(mode.o):/home/jitcomm/intern_GUI/jit24_test_v2/cgi_src/cgi_module/mode.c:56: first defined here
../../lib/libcgi_module.a(users.o): In function `saveUser':
users.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
users.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
users.c:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
users.c:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `mysql_query'
users.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
users.c:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
```

So I write some sample code and I can run well when I use my program with this line

```
gcc -o saveUser $(mysql_config --cflags) saveUser.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

It works well.

So next step, I try to put my coding in CGI.
I still got those undefined reference again. 
Here is my Makefile.basic

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
#CC=powerpc-linux-gcc
CP=/usr/bin/cp
CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs)

www=/var/www
htdocs=/htdocs
cgi_bin=/cgi-bin
config=/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

What should I do ? Where it goes wrong ? Help me please. I have been searching on the internet for a week but still can't get the solution. I guess it's in **makefile.basic** and the linking to mysql is wrong.

Thanks

**Update :**

here is my **top level Makefile**

```
    ROOT=.
     CURDIR=$(shell /bin/pwd)
     JITCOMM_INSTALL=$(ROOT)/install

     include $(ROOT)/Makefile.basic

     #set root directory
     SUB_DIRS = cgi_src
     SUB_DIRS += check_update
     SUB_DIRS += loadconfig
SUB_DIRS += keepalive
SUB_DIRS += script
SUB_DIRS += server
SUB_DIRS += startproxy
SUB_DIRS += net_stats
#SUB_DIRS += ../sniffer_gui
#SUB_DIRS += java 

all:
ifneq ($(SUB_DIRS), )
        @for i in $(SUB_DIRS) ; do if [ ! -d $(CURDIR)/$${i} ]; then continue; fi; \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i}; make || exit; cd $(CURDIR); done
endif

clean:
        @rm -f $(ROOT)/lib/*
        @rm -rf $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)
ifneq ($(SUB_DIRS), )
        @for i in $(SUB_DIRS) ; do if [ ! -d $(CURDIR)/$${i} ]; then continue; fi; \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i}; make clean || exit; cd $(CURDIR); done
endif


install: all
        @rm -rf $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/etc
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/etc/acpro
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/etc/syslog-ng
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/etc/apache2
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/etc/apache2/sites-available
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/var
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/var/www
        @mkdir $(JITCOMM_INSTALL)/var/www/cgi-bin
```

Here is my **Makefile in cgi-src folder**

```
ROOT=../
CURDIR=$(shell /bin/pwd)

include $(ROOT)/Makefile.basic

#set root directory
SUB_DIRS = util
SUB_DIRS += cgi_util
SUB_DIRS += cgi_module

#Must be last
SUB_DIRS += cgi_main

all:
ifneq ($(SUB_DIRS), )
        @for i in $(SUB_DIRS) ; do if [ ! -d $(CURDIR)/$${i} ]; then continue; fi; \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i}; make || exit; cd $(CURDIR); done
endif

clean:
ifneq ($(SUB_DIRS), )
        @for i in $(SUB_DIRS) ; do if [ ! -d $(CURDIR)/$${i} ]; then continue; fi; \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i}; make clean || exit; cd $(CURDIR); done
endif


install:

ifneq ($(SUB_DIRS), )
        @for i in $(SUB_DIRS) ; do if [ ! -d $(CURDIR)/$${i} ]; then continue; fi; \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i}; make install || exit; cd $(CURDIR); done
endif
```

Here is my **Makefile.basic**

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
#CC=powerpc-linux-gcc
CP=/usr/bin/cp
CFLAGS=-g -Wall $(shell mysql_config --cflags) $(shell mysql_config --libs)

www=/var/www
htdocs=/htdocs
cgi_bin=/cgi-bin
config=/etc/apache2/sites-available/default


INSTALL_DIR=$(pwd)/.install
```

**Latest Update :**

**Makefile in cgi_module**

```
#set common variant
.SUFFIXES: .c .h .o

ROOT=../../
include $(ROOT)/Makefile.basic

#LINK_NAME = changepass.cgi login.cgi network.cgi reboot.cgi shutdown.cgi
LINK_NAME = login.cgi

INCS = -I../include
INCS += -I../../cgi_src/util/include
OBJES=../../lib/


TARGET = libcgi_module.a
#don't change below
LIB_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
CLEAN_OBJS = $(LIB_OBJS) $(TARGET)

INST_OBJ = $(TARGET)
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCS) -o $@ $<

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(LIB_OBJS)
        $(AR) -vsur $@ $^ 
        @cp $(TARGET) $(OBJES)

clean:
        -@rm -rf $(CLEAN_OBJS)

install:
```

Comment: could you post the makefile located in cgi_module (with the gcc call) ?

Comment: I post it under latest update , Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
#CC=powerpc-linux-gcc
CP=/usr/bin/cp
CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(shell mysql_config --cflags) $(shell mysql_config --libs)


foo:
    @echo "CFLAGS are $(CFLAGS)"
```

and launch `make foo`

Comment: @cedric >> Sorry for my late reply. I still got the error. Is there anyway to overcome this problem ? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @kevin : try to create a foo target in your makefile to display the CFLAGS value
`foo:
   @echo "CFLAGS are $(CFLAGS)"`

and launch `make foo`

Comment: @cedric >> What's foo ? Sorry about my ignorance I just start using C 2.5 months ago. Can you elaborate it a little bit ? Thanks !!!

Comment: @cedric >> Thanks. But when I make foo , it just shows "  
CFLAGS are -g -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient    " but don't do anything else.

Comment: @kevin : well, it should works.... could you show us where in your makefile and how is called gcc ?

Comment: @cedric , I'll update my question, pls check it for me. Thanks for your help.